# Not able to match or compare two dates

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am not able to match or compare two dates **one from Database and second is current date**.I have five checkboxes. When 1st user checkes a checkbox and insert its value by clicking the save button. 2nd time when he check 2 or more checkboxes Now here I want to update last record by date. I set date as primary key in that table.

**NamazCounterActivity**

```
package com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;


public class NamazCounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper mydb;
    CheckBox cb1,cb2,cb3,cb4,cb5;
    Button B1,B2,B3;
    TextView tv;
    int vcb1=0,vcb2=0,vcb3=0,vcb4=0,vcb5=0;
    Date date = new Date();
    String a="1";

    public static final String SHARED_PREF = "sharedPrefs";
    public static final String CHECK1 = "check1";
    public static final String CHECK2 = "check2";
    public static final String CHECK3 = "check3";
    public static final String CHECK4 = "check4";
    public static final String CHECK5 = "check5";
    private Boolean chb1,chb2,chb3,chb4,chb5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_namaz_counter);
        try {
            mydb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        tv = findViewById(R.id.textView24);
        cb1 = findViewById(R.id.namaz1);
        cb2 = findViewById(R.id.namaz2);
        cb3 = findViewById(R.id.namaz3);
        cb4 = findViewById(R.id.namaz4);
        cb5 = findViewById(R.id.namaz5);
        B1 = findViewById(R.id.result);

        B2 = findViewById(R.id.dateee);
        B3 = findViewById(R.id.sumr);

        c_date();

        B1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor c = mydb.getAllData1();
                if (c.moveToFirst())
                {
                    if(mydb.date().equals(c.getString(0)))
                    {
                        Updateingdata();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        InsertingData();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    InsertingData();
                }
                SaveData();
            }
        });

        B3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Cursor c = mydb.getAllData();

                if(c.getCount() == 0)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(NamazCounterActivity.this,"Empty",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                while (c.moveToNext())
                {
                    stringBuffer.append("ID: " +c.getString(0 )+"\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Fajar: " +c.getString(1)+"\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Zohr: " +c.getString(2)+"\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Asr: " +c.getString(3)+"\n");
                    stringBuffer.append("Magrib: " +c.getString(4)+"\n" );
                    stringBuffer.append("Isha: " +c.getString(5)+"\n");
                }
                showData("Data",stringBuffer.toString());
            }
        });
        //home button
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        //functions for save old values
        loadData();
        updateViews();
    }

    //function for going back to previous activity
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            finish();
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void InsertingData()
    {
        if(cb1.isChecked())
        {
            vcb1 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb1 = 0;
        }
        if(cb2.isChecked())
        {
            vcb2 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb2 = 0;
        }
        if(cb3.isChecked())
        {
            vcb3 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb3 = 0;
        }
        if(cb4.isChecked())
        {
            vcb4 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb4 = 0;
        }
        if(cb5.isChecked())
        {
            vcb5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb5 = 0;
        }

        boolean result = mydb.InsertData(date().toString(),Integer.toString(vcb1),Integer.toString(vcb2),Integer.toString(vcb3),Integer.toString(vcb4),Integer.toString(vcb5));
        if(result == true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(NamazCounterActivity.this, "Prayer Saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NamazCounterActivity.this, "Some Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public void Updateingdata()
    {
        if(cb1.isChecked())
        {
            vcb1 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb1 = 0;
        }
        if(cb2.isChecked())
        {
            vcb2 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb2 = 0;
        }
        if(cb3.isChecked())
        {
            vcb3 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb3 = 0;
        }
        if(cb4.isChecked())
        {
            vcb4 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb4 = 0;
        }
        if(cb5.isChecked())
        {
            vcb5 = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            vcb5 = 0;
        }

        boolean res = mydb.UpdateData(B2.getText().toString(),Integer.toString(vcb1),Integer.toString(vcb2),Integer.toString(vcb3),Integer.toString(vcb4),Integer.toString(vcb5));
        if(res == true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(NamazCounterActivity.this,"Data Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(NamazCounterActivity.this,"Data Not Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    //for date ()
    public void c_date() {
        date.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); //set to current time
        B2.setText(date.toString());
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEE, MMM dd, yyyy");
        B2.setText(dateFormat.format(date));

    }

    public void SaveData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        editor.putBoolean(CHECK1, cb1.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK2, cb2.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK3, cb3.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK4, cb4.isChecked());
        editor.putBoolean(CHECK5, cb5.isChecked());

        editor.apply();

    }

    public void loadData()
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF,MODE_PRIVATE);
        chb1 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK1, false);
        chb2 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK2, false);
        chb3 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK3, false);
        chb4 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK4, false);
        chb5 = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(CHECK5, false);
    }

    public void updateViews()
    {
        cb1.setChecked(chb1);
        cb2.setChecked(chb2);
        cb3.setChecked(chb3);
        cb4.setChecked(chb4);
        cb5.setChecked(chb5);
    }

    public void showData(String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

    public java.sql.Date date()
    {
        long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);
        return date;
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
package com.example.shakeelmughal.assanislam;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.Date;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;
import static java.time.LocalTime.now;

/**
 * Created by Shakeel Mughal on 5/30/2018.
 */

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public Context context;
    private SQLiteDatabase db2;
    public AssetManager mngr;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    private Resources mResources;
    private InputStream inputstream = null;
    private final static String Dbname = "NamazCounter.db";
    private final static String Tbname = "DailyWork";
    private final static String Tbname2 = "items";
    private final static String Col_1 = "ID";
    private final static String Col_2 = "Fajar";
    private final static String Col_3 = "Zohr";
    private final static String Col_4 = "Asr";
    private final static String Col_5 = "Magrib";
    private final static String Col_6 = "Isha";


    private final static String NCol_1 = "date_for";
    private final static String NCol_2 = "fajr";
    private final static String NCol_3 = "shurooq";
    private final static String NCol_4 = "dhuhr";
    private final static String NCol_5 = "asr";
    private final static String NCol_6 = "maghrib";
    private final static String NCol_7 = "isha";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) throws IOException {
        super(context, Dbname, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        mResources = context.getResources();

        mngr = context.getAssets();
        db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //namaz counter
        final String Table1 = "CREATE TABLE "+Tbname+"(ID PRIMARY KEY TEXT, Fajar TEXT, Zohr TEXT, Asr TEXT, Magrib TEXT, Isha TEXT)";
        //for namaz timing
        final String Table2 = "CREATE TABLE "+Tbname2+"(date_for TEXT, fajr TEXT, shurooq TEXT, dhuhr TEXT, asr TEXT, maghrib TEXT,isha TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(Table1);
        db.execSQL(Table2);
        Log.d(TAG, "DataBase Created");

        try {
            readDataToDb(db);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ Tbname);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ Tbname2);
        onCreate(db);



    }

    public void openDatabase() {

        String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(Dbname).getPath();
        if (db != null) {
            db.isOpen();
            return;
        }
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(dbPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    public void closeDatabase() {
        if (db != null) {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    //Json fun
    private String readJsonDataFromFile() throws IOException {

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            String jsonDataString = null;

            inputstream = mngr.open("NamazTiming.json");
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(inputstream, "UTF-8"));
            while ((jsonDataString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(jsonDataString);
            }

        } finally {
            if (inputstream != null) {
                inputstream.close();
            }
        }
        return new String(builder);
    }

    public void readDataToDb(SQLiteDatabase db) throws IOException, JSONException {
        final String date = "date_for";
        final String namaz1 = "fajr";
        final String namaz2 = "shurooq";
        final String namaz3 = "dhuhr";
        final String namaz4 = "asr";
        final String namaz5 = "maghrib";
        final String namaz6 = "isha";

        try {
            String jsonDataString = readJsonDataFromFile();
            JSONArray jsonfileJSONArray = new JSONArray(jsonDataString);
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonfileJSONArray.length(); i++) {
                String dateid;
                String nmz1;
                String nmz2;
                String nmz3;
                String nmz4;
                String nmz5;
                String nmz6;


                JSONObject jsonfileObject = jsonfileJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);

                dateid = jsonfileObject.getString(date);
                nmz1 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz1);
                nmz2 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz2);
                nmz3 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz3);
                nmz4 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz4);
                nmz5 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz5);
                nmz6 = jsonfileObject.getString(namaz6);

                ContentValues jsonfilevalues = new ContentValues();
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_1, dateid);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_2, nmz1);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_3, nmz2);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_4, nmz3);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_5, nmz4);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_6, nmz5);
                jsonfilevalues.put(NCol_7, nmz6);
                long rowID=  db.insert(Tbname2, null, jsonfilevalues);
                if(rowID>-1){
                    int catid=0;
                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT "+ NCol_1 + " FROM "+ Tbname2+" where "+ NCol_1 + "='" + now() + "'" , null);
                    cursor.moveToFirst();
                    if (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                        catid = (cursor.getInt(0));
                    }

                    cursor.close();
                    JSONArray jsonitemsarray= (JSONArray) jsonfileObject.get("itemsList");
                    readitem(db,jsonitemsarray);
                }

                Log.d(TAG, "Inserted sucessfully" + jsonfilevalues);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    private void readitem(SQLiteDatabase db,JSONArray jsonfileJSONArray) throws IOException, JSONException {

        final String date1 = "date_for";
        final String namaz1 = "fajr";
        final String namaz2 = "shurooq";
        final String namaz3 = "dhuhr";
        final String namaz4 = "asr";
        final String namaz5 = "maghrib";
        final String namaz6 = "isha";

        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonfileJSONArray.length(); i++) {


                String Did;
                String nmzz1 ;
                String nmzz2 ;
                String nmzz3 ;
                String nmzz4 ;
                String nmzz5 ;
                String nmzz6 ;

                JSONObject jsonfileObject1 = jsonfileJSONArray.getJSONObject(i);


                Did = jsonfileObject1.getString(date1);
                nmzz1 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz1);
                nmzz2 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz2);
                nmzz3 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz3);
                nmzz4 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz4);
                nmzz5 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz5);
                nmzz6 = jsonfileObject1.getString(namaz6);



                ContentValues jsonfilevalues1 = new ContentValues();

                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_1, Did);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_2, nmzz1);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_3, nmzz2);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_4, nmzz3);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_5, nmzz4);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_6, nmzz5);
                jsonfilevalues1.put(NCol_7, nmzz6);
                db.insert(Tbname2, null, jsonfilevalues1);

                Log.d(TAG, "Inserted sucessfully" + jsonfilevalues1);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    //inserting for counter
    public boolean InsertData(String d_date, String Fjr, String zhr, String assr, String mgrb, String isa)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Col_1,d_date);
        contentValues.put(Col_2,Fjr);
        contentValues.put(Col_3,zhr);
        contentValues.put(Col_4,assr);
        contentValues.put(Col_5,mgrb);
        contentValues.put(Col_6,isa);
        long success = db.insert(Tbname,null,contentValues);
        if(success == -1)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public boolean UpdateData(String id,String n1, String n2, String n3,String n4,String n5)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(Col_1,id);
        contentValues.put(Col_2,n1);
        contentValues.put(Col_3,n2);
        contentValues.put(Col_4,n3);
        contentValues.put(Col_3,n4);
        contentValues.put(Col_4,n5);

        db.update(Tbname,contentValues,"ID = ?", new String[]{id});
        return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllDataForNamaz()
    {
        openDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+ Tbname2 + " WHERE date_for = "+ date(),null);
        closeDatabase();
        return cs;
    }
    public Date date()
    {
        long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();
        java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);
        return date;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cs = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  "+ Tbname,null);
        return cs;
    }



    public Cursor getAllData1()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cs = db.rawQuery("SELECT ID FROM  "+ Tbname,null);
        return cs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post only the relevant code. And use logcat to print both the date as the string.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in 2004.

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to convert all your date into timestamp and use only timestamp for comparaison (you can also save date as timestamp in your database) :

```
System.currentTimeMillis() // Current timestamp
date.time // timestamp of the SQL Date object

if (timestamp1 > timestamp2) {
    // timestamp1 after timestamp2
} else if (timestamp1 < timestamp2) {
    // timestamp1 before timestamp2
} else {
    // timestamp1 == timestamp2
}
```

Comment: How I do that??

Comment: I edited my answer, the timestamp is the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT

Answer (score 0):

Try this code first convert data into this format..."dd/mm/yyyy"

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date strDate = sdf.parse(valid_until);
if (new Date().after(strDate)) {
// define log
}
```

Comment: Where to use it? On button click where I matching date?